# How to get command line for OpenCLFunctionLoad?

Tags: gpu, ccompilerdriver, opencllink

Is there a way how to get the command used to compile my OpenCL kernel, when I use `OpenCLFunctionLoad[]`?

When I use `"ShellCommandFunction"->Print`, I receive just the parameters (like "`-DOPENCLLINK_USING_INTEL -Dmint=long -DReal_t=float`"), but not the full command - compiler, paths, files, etc.

I am currently hunting some bugs with C preprocessor and different behavior of the compiler on various platforms (Linux vs. macOS) so it would be really helpful to be able to replicate the exact command line which is used by *Mathematica*.